# cannot find getActivity() and several errors after migrating to androidx

Tags: android

```
error: cannot find symbol class Fragment
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
error: cannot find symbol variable super
error: cannot find symbol method getString(int)
```

Comment: Add your code with question .

Comment: Kindly provide complete logcat error stack

Answer (score 0):

I think the root problem is the compiler cannot find the `Fragment` class. The `getActivity()` and `getString(int)` exist in the `Fragment` class. So you try to import the `Fragment` class. The problems will be solved. I hopes it helps!